# How to add date/time (both together like crystal report) picker in power BI

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, crystal-reports, report

I was trying to add date and time picker using visual. I can select or specify the time in filters by selecting filter type to advanced, But is there any way to do it in visualization? I tried using Slicer but it only solved the date issue I still cant select time.

Bellow are the pictures what I am using and what I want:

[Specifying the time in filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cisP.png)

[Using slicer did solve the date issue but not the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYiBP.png)

[Crystal Report snippet, what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h30dq.png)

Comment: There isn't an out-of-the-box visual slicer that supports date and time, and I haven't seen a custom visual slicer for the same either. Perhaps consider having a slicer for the date, and separate slicer for the time (with sensible increments).